# Summarize by unique records by values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

| ID1 | ID2 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | x |  |
| A | B |  | x |
| A | C |  |  |
| A | C |  |  |

I want my output to be the below table. Logic is that for each unique combination of ID1 and ID2, I want to have col 1 display "X" if it exists in any of the combinations. If no "X" exists in the entire combination, then I want to display it as blank.

| ID1 | ID2 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | x | x |
| A | C |  |  |

How do I do that?

Comment: You can use the MAX aggregation function on col1 and col2, aggregate over ID1 and ID2, you'll get the output you need.

Comment: Why is there a col2 here ? Do we need to do something with col2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) aggregation function on "*col1*" and "*col2*", group over "*ID1*" and "*ID2*". In this way you'll remove the `NULL` values for each combination of ids, where there's at least a non-null value.

```
SELECT ID1,
       ID2,
       MAX(col1) AS col1,
       MAX(col2) AS col2
FROM tab
GROUP BY ID1,
         ID2
```